# Class Holiday in Pandas doesn't manage leap year -> ValueError

Tags: python, pandas

This code return `ValueError: day is out of range for month` :

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
import datetime as dt

class MyHolidays(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [Holiday('Sapeur',month=2,day=29)]

cal=MyHolidays()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = dt.date(2020, 2, 1)
    myholidays =cal.holidays(start, start + MonthEnd())
```

How do you make this code work in non-leap years?
I thought class Holiday handled that, didn't you?

Thx a lot for advance.

ps: 2020 is a leap year but not 2019 or 2021.
ps2: I seek a better solution than :

```
rules = [Holiday('Sapeur',year=2020, month=2,day=29),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2021, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2022, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2023, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('Sapeur',year=2024, month=2,day=29),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2025, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2026, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('NoSapeur',year=2027, month=2,day=28),
         Holiday('Sapeur',year=2028, month=2,day=29),
         ...]
```

Because I'm on vacation every February and I make my rules with:

```
cejour=pd.Timestamp.today()
RÈGLES=[]
 mois=2
 for jour in pd.date_range(début_mois:=cejour.replace(month=mois, day=1), début_mois+MonthEnd(), normalize=True):
 RÈGLES+=[Holiday('Vacances Février',month=mois, day=jour.day)]

class MyHolidays(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = RÈGLES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own observance

```
def leap_year(dt):
    if dt.is_leap_year:
        return dt + MonthEnd()

class MyHolidays(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [Holiday('Sapeur', month=2, day=28, observance=leap_year)]


cal = MyHolidays()
start = dt.date(2020, 2, 1)
myholidays =cal.holidays(start, start + MonthEnd())

print(myholidays) # DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-29'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If you try this with a non leap year then it will assign nothing

```
start = dt.date(2019, 2, 1)
myholidays =cal.holidays(start, start + MonthEnd())

print(myholidays) # DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thx a lot, It's work. Great.
For my Holidyas, I must write in rules:
`rules = [Holiday('Sapeur', month=2, day=28, observance=leap_year),
            Holiday('Sapeur', month=2, day=28)]`
Do you know a more elegant method for combined this 2 rules ?

Comment: Question, is Sapeur always the last day of February?

Comment: No, only [29/02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Bougie_du_Sapeur)
My example is confusing

Comment: Let me get it straight, Spaeur in only on 29/02, but in the first comment, there is a need for Sapeur on 28/2 ... why?

Comment: My first comment introduce confusing ! Sorry.
My goal is to put the **whole** month of February (leap or not) on vacation...

Comment: At the best of my knowledge, I don't know the answer, `observance` can only return one datetime object at the time, because it executed from a `DatetimeIndex.map`, the other idea I had was to add both dates ( 28/02 and 29/02 ) to the `DatetimeIndex`, but this seems also complicated because it is automatically generated from `Holiday._reference_dates` based on, one an only one `day` provided on the constructor.